# React, adding components in component

Tags: reactjs

I started to learn React and I hit first wall.

I have a list component which should display a list of rows + button for adding a new row.

All is in those 2 gists:

https://gist.github.com/matiit/7b361dee3f878502e10a

https://gist.github.com/matiit/8bac28c4d5c6ce3993c7

The addRow method is executed on click, because I can see the console.log, but no InputRows are added.

Can't really see why.

This is a little updated (dirty) code which doesn't work either.
Now it's only one file:

```js
var InputList = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            rowCount: 1
        }
    },

    getClassNames: function () {
        if (this.props.type === 'incomes') {
            return 'col-md-4 ' + this.props.type;
        } else if (this.props.type === 'expenses') {
            return 'col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 ' + this.props.type;
        }
    },

    addRow: function () {
        this.state.rowCount = this.state.rowCount + 1;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var inputs = [];
        for (var i=0;i<this.state.rowCount; i++) {
            inputs.push(i);
        }

        console.log(inputs);

        return (
            <div className={ this.getClassNames() }>
                {inputs.map(function (result) {
                     return <InputRow key={result} />;
                })}
                <div className="row">
                    <button onClick={this.addRow} className="btn btn-success">Add more</button>    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.render()` doesn't do anything.  If you look at the function, it simply does some calculations and returns some data (the virtual dom nodes).

You should be using setState instead of directly modifying it.  This is cleaner, and allows react to know something's changed.

```
addRow: function () {
    this.setState({rowCount: this.state.rowCount + 1});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store list of components in state.
Instead store the income row count and expense row count in state.
Use click handler to increment these counts.
Use render method to generate required rows based on count.

Comment: I did something similar just couple minutes before your comment:
 * https://gist.github.com/matiit/f2cf0059dec0a4054cb2
 * https://gist.github.com/matiit/a3665b0725b16cc4a7b3

Doesn't work either.